# If condition broken: get into when condition is false and skip lines

Tags: java, android, algorithm, if-statement, android-studio

Programming with java on android, I'm facing a very weird problem those days.

This is basically my condition:

```
ContentValues values = null;
boolean condition=((!(name.equals(stateString))) && (!(stateString.equals(""))));

     if(condition)
     {
                   // UPDATE STATE NAME INTO DB
                  values = new ContentValues();
                  values.put("state_name", stateString);
                  sql.update("STATE", values, "_id=" + state, null);
     }
```

The problem is, when `condition` is false, the IDE is going into the condition anyway, and it skips the two first lines.

Basically, instead of skipping the statement, it directly goes to :

```
sql.update("STATE", values, "_id=" + state, null);
```

even if `condition` is false...

I have no idea of why this is happening. I try to make the condition simpler, but the problem remains. I also checked for a possible `;` I could have forget after a condition, but everything seems to be good.

I have to add that this is happening in an `AsyncTask` during the `doInBackground` process. I'm using android-studio.

Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT 2**

Because I'm getting downvoted and if you think it shouldn't happen or if it works for you, please read this.

- First, this is running on an AsyncTask, after an API call ( using HttpsURLConnection )
- Then, I'm Running **THE SAME PROCESS FOR THE COUNTRY LIST BEFORE ( before doing that for the states)**. Here the  `values` variables is initialized, and this one is reused after because the two lines skipped were suppose to initialize it, and the follow statement sql.update() is called when it shouldnt.... As it skips the two first lines, it update the DB with values which are not properly initialized, which I can clearly see when I'm checking the DB manually. **So the problem is not the debugger: The way the datas are set in the DB prove that DEBUGGER IS RIGHT when it says THAT THE APP RUNS THE SQL UPDATE STATEMENT WHEN THE CONDITION IS FALSE. So YES: the app is running the third line of the statement in the if condition when the condition is false.**
- And then, the db is encrypted, using sqlcipher. This db is by the way already populated and provided with the app. **THIS IS HAPPENING DURING THE UPDATE PROCESS IN BACKGROUND**
- Finally, clearing the code, rebuilding it, restarting the IDE, Invalidating the cache etc... doesnt give any satisfying results.

**EDIT 1**

The following condition is the full code. It's called in a loop.

```
if (state != -1) {
                        sql.close();
                        sql = db.getWritableDatabase(password);
                        // UPDATE STATE IF CHANGES
                        String query = "SELECT state_name,state_local_name,state_country FROM STATE WHERE _id=" + state;
                        Cursor cursor = sql.rawQuery(query, null);
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
                        {
                            ContentValues values = null;
                            String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("state_name"));
                            String localName=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("state_local_name"));

                            // UPDATE NAME
                            try {

                                if((!(name.equals(stateString))) && (!(stateString.equals(""))))
                                {
                                    // UPDATE STATE NAME INTO DB
                                    values = new ContentValues();
                                    values.put("state_name", stateString);
                                    sql.update("STATE", values, "_id=" + state, null);
                                }
                            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                Log.i("APP", "err3");
                            }
                            // UPDATE LOCAL NAME
                            try {
                                if((!(localName.equals(local_state)))&&(!(local_state.equals(""))))
                                {   // UPDATE STATE LOCAL NAME INTO DB
                                    values = new ContentValues();
                                    values.put("state_local_name", local_state);
                                    sql.update("STATE", values, "_id=" + state, null);
                                }
                            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                Log.i("APP", "err4");
                            }
                            // UPDATE COUNTRY
                            try {
                                if((cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("state_country"))) != country && country != -1)
                                {
                                    // UPDATE COUNTRY ID FOR STATE INTO DB
                                    values = new ContentValues();
                                    values.put("state_country", country);
                                    sql.update("STATE", values, "_id=" + state, null);
                                }
                            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                Log.i("APP", "err5");
                            }
                        }
                        if (cursor != null) cursor.close();

                        // STATE ID VALUE FOR STATION UPDATE
                        newValues.put("station_state", state);
                    } else {
                        if (!stateString.equals("") || !local_state.equals("") || country != -1) {

                            sql.close();
                            sql = db.getWritableDatabase(password);
                            // INSERT NEW STATE IN DB
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                            if (!stateString.equals("")) values.put("state_name", stateString);
                            if (!local_state.equals(""))
                                values.put("state_local_name", local_state);
                            if (country != -1) values.put("state_country", country);
                            sql.insert("STATE", null, values);

                            // GET NEW STATE ID
                            state = MyDb.getIdStateFromName(db, stateString);
                            newValues.put("station_state", state);
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "IDE is going"? Are you debugging, with a breakpoint on `values = null` and stepping through the code? Or what?

Comment: did you debuged code using breakpoint?

Comment: @Sabeeh Yes. I used breakpoints, Logs, even my own coworkers :D Using the step by step debug of android studio, the IDE directly goes to the line sql.update(...).
Values remains null, so it clearly has not been initialized, and the values not put into. Also, the breakpoints I put on values = new ContentValues(); and values.put("state_name", countryString); are not reached.

Comment: @Virthuss check again may `sql.update` called from somewhere else means may be you put another `sql.update` after that condition. Also make sure this by setting break point on both `values = new ContentValues();` and `sql.update(...);`

Comment: @Sabeeh I have several condition like this one following each other. Do you think it could be the problem knowing that this problem happens in EVERYONE of them?

Comment: @Virthuss can you post full code with sample data

Comment: Please try to build a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I cannot as it's located in a background process, using an encrypted db. I know it' should be working in a common situation but in my case it's not...

Comment: Any particular reason you're comparing column `state_name` to variable `stateString`, and if different, updating column `state_name` with the value of variable ***`countryString`***? --- Also, when you said you "used Logs", did that mean you tried insert a log statement before *every* statement, with an increasing number and values of all variables used in the statement immediately after the inserted log statement?

Comment: A little trouble when I copy and past, my bad. But thats not the problem.

Comment: @Virthuss are your other update statements working properly?

Comment: @Droidwala kind of. I think the thread is making the mess on this part, I'll try another approach for this.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to go in if condition with false condition and also to skip the code. above mention situation normally happens when the code is not loaded so please stop the application save and clean build the code and run the application.

Comment: I did all of that. Clearing and rebuilding the code, invalidate the cache, unplugged the device, uninstall the APK.I checked thousand of times, I used the logs, the debugger, the breakpoints with or without a condition. And the problem is still there. Then I tried without the debugger and with some other classes to manually check the values in the db and I'm formal, something is wrong there. I know that its technically not possible but what i'm describing IS ACTUALLY HAPPENING for a reason I don't know.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code :

```
 ContentValues values;

    boolean condition = ((!name.equals(stateString)) && (!stateString.isEmpty())) // Changes in Condition


         if(condition)
         {
                // do your code when condition is equal to true

                       // UPDATE STATE NAME INTO DB
                      values = new ContentValues();
                      values.put("state_name", countryString);
                      sql.update("STATE", values, "_id=" + state, null);
         }else{
                 // do your code when condition is equal to false
         }
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't fix the problem... Making the condition simpler doesn't change anything as well...

Comment: @Virthuss : What is there in stateString and name ?

Comment: Some states name. But the condition is valid, as I have the expected result stored in condition. Basically here my if(condition) is similar to if(false), but the IDE still go into the condition skipping the two first lines.

Comment: @Virthuss : see if condition equals false it won't go into the loop. It will only into the loop when it is true. And I have checked this in my code and works perfectly.

Comment: @ KishuDroid I know how a condition work. It's not going on the full statement but just on the last line. I'm use to java, I know that something is wrong and how a condition is working....

Comment: I have debugged it and it didn't skipping any lines. There might be problem in your debugging.

Comment: Did you put it in an async task? Did you encrypt the database? Do you run it after an API call? If no, then you are not in my case.